# How to make a header animation appear with an onload event in javascript only (no jQuery allowed)

Tags: javascript

I am trying to obtain an animation effect with a header of a site. The animation process is simple: I just want the header to slide from top -120px to bottom and remain at that position. I managed to make it run from a code snippet which I found on the internet but it only works with the onclick event listener. When I try to change it to work with the onload event listener it won't work and I don't know what's the cause of the problem.

Here is the code of the main page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
        <script src="script/headJS.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
        if(!isset($_SESSION['user'])){
            require_once("pages/firstPage.php");
        }else{
            require_once("pages/secondPage.php");
        }
        ?>
        <script src="script/bodyJS.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

So I load with PHP another page called firstPage.php whenever the user is not logged in. The code of firstPage.php is the following:

```
<div class="container" onclick="move(this.children[0]);">
    <div class="antet">
        <p id="logo"><a href="index.php">Web Ideas</a></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

and the bodyJS.js script file haves the following code:

```
function move(elem) {
    var top = -130;

    function frame() {
        top++;
        elem.style.top = top + "px";

        if (top == 0) {
            clearInterval(id);
        }
    }
    var id = setInterval(frame, 10);
}
```

the CSS for the page is the following:

```
body, ul, ol, p, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, table, tr, td, dd, dt, dl, div, pre {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
}
body{
    position: relative;
    background: #a9a9a9;
    font-size: 16px;
}
.container{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    min-width: 1349px;
    min-height: 1200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.antet{
    position: relative;
    width: 1349px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #19355b;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-bottom: 2px solid white;
}
@font-face{
    font-family: 'Iceland';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    src: local('Iceland'), local('Iceland-Regular'), url("http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/iceland/v3/F6LYTZLHrG9BNYXRjU7RSw.woff") format("woff");
}
@-webkit-keyframes neon{
    from{
        text-shadow: 0 0 10px #fff, 0 0 20px #fff, 0 0 30px #fff, 0 0 40px #a9a9a9, 0 0 70px #a9a9a9, 0 0 80px #a9a9a9,
            0 0 100px #a9a9a9, 0 0 150px #a9a9a9;
    }
    to{
        text-shadow: 0 0 5px #fff, 0 0 10px #fff, 0 0 15px #fff, 0 0 20px #a9a9a9, 0 0 35px #a9a9a9, 0 0 40px #a9a9a9,
            0 0 50px #a9a9a9, 0 0 75px #a9a9a9;
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes neon {
    from {
        text-shadow: 0 0 10px #fff, 0 0 20px #fff, 0 0 30px #fff, 0 0 40px #a9a9a9, 0 0 70px #a9a9a9, 0 0 80px #a9a9a9, 0 0 100px #a9a9a9, 0 0 150px #a9a9a9;
    }
    to {
        text-shadow: 0 0 5px #fff, 0 0 10px #fff, 0 0 15px #fff, 0 0 20px #a9a9a9, 0 0 35px #a9a9a9, 0 0 40px #a9a9a9, 0 0 50px #a9a9a9, 0 0 75px #a9a9a9;
    }
}
@keyframes neon {
    from {
        text-shadow: 0 0 10px #fff, 0 0 20px #fff, 0 0 30px #fff, 0 0 40px #a9a9a9, 0 0 70px #a9a9a9, 0 0 80px #a9a9a9, 0 0 100px #a9a9a9, 0 0 150px #a9a9a9;
    }
    to {
        text-shadow: 0 0 5px #fff, 0 0 10px #fff, 0 0 15px #fff, 0 0 20px #a9a9a9, 0 0 35px #a9a9a9, 0 0 40px #a9a9a9, 0 0 50px #a9a9a9, 0 0 75px #a9a9a9;
    }
}
#logo{
    position: relative;
    width: 321px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#logo a:hover{
    color: #ffffff;
}
#logo a{
    text-decoration: none;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s;
    transition: all 0.5s;
}
p:nth-child(1) a{
    font-size: 5em;
    color: rgba(37, 220, 57, 0.8);
    font-family: 'Iceland', Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
p:nth-child(1) a:hover{
    -webkit-animation: neon 1.5s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
    -moz-animation: neon 1.5s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
    animation: neon 1.5s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
}
```

everything works just fine with the onclick event listener but when I try to switch it to onload event listener the page will load but without any animation. The position of the children div will not change. I thought this is because of the DOM that needed to be loaded and afterwards to fire the event listener so I switched the `<script></script>` tags in the bottom of my body element in the page. How can I solve this out ? Any help or hints are welcome, thanks in advance guys.

[JSFiddle with onclick event listener that works](https://jsfiddle.net/bookw0rm/8haz2yod/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've added an event listener that works. **You just needed to change the way you are referencing the div when you call your move function**:

```
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() { 
   move(document.querySelector(".container").children[0]); 
});
```

Just place this at the top of your bodyJS.js file (above the move function).

See this working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/sgLqz58n/3/

Comment: Infinite loop of thanks for your fast response and clean code answer. Not only the code works, but it also meets the W3C DOM Standards as you also said. Million thanks, you helped me a lot.

Comment: @bookw0rm Happy to help!  Don't forget to up-vote!  Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I've set with absolute positioning, but you can also change that property in `.scrolled` class. You can look at this bin for your solution

http://jsbin.com/qogasodetu/edit?html,css,js,output

Changed CSS -

```
.container{
    position: fixed;
    top: -130px;
    transition: all linear 250ms;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    min-width: 1349px;
    min-height: 1200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.scrolled {
    top: 0;
}
```

Changed JS

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var elm = document.querySelector('.container');
    setTimeout(function() {
        elm.classList.add('scrolled');
    }, 500);
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply on this matter. The code indeed works well but I have a problem with the animation going too fast and that's the reason why I've marked @Scott Marcus answer for the question. His code looks much more cleaner and it does exactly what I need it to do and also respects the W3C DOM Standards. Thank you also for your time and effort.

Comment: @bookw0rm I don't mind you choosing other answer if they serve your purpose. Although one thing to note, my solutions is completely confront to DOM specs and uses correct standards throughout.

I don't like CSS stuff with JS and hence my solutions was mostly CSS with minor JS interaction

Comment: Also to note, you can totally control the animation speed by controlling `transition` property on `.container`

Comment: thanks for your time and your help, you gave me a different point of view for code manner and I appreciate your time and effort a lot.

Answer (score -1):

You can try triggering click on page load.

You can also try calling `move` manually, but I'd suggest to use click event itself. But if you have some special handling on `click`, then you can call `move()`.

Also, you can use `load` or `DOMContentLoaded` event to call function.

---

As rightly suggested by @Scott Marcus, its better to use `window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){})` instead of `window.onload = function(){}`. Following is an updated fiddle.

**[Updated JSFiddle - Move](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/8haz2yod/4/)**

---

Following are demos

#### Use Click

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/8haz2yod/1/).

```js
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById("header").click();
}
```

---

#### Use Move

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/8haz2yod/2/)

```js
window.onload = function() {
  move(document.getElementById("header").children[0])
}
```

Comment: You should avoid using event handling properties of DOM objects as this doesn't follow the W3C DOM Event Handling standard and doesn't allow for multiple callback registrations to a single event. Use addEventListener() instead.  In addition, `DOMContentLoaded` would be better than `load` in this case, as no images are being used, so the banner won't have to wait for all the images to load before sliding down.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Thanks for the suggestion. I have updated my answer and credited you.

Comment: But, your answer is still wrong because you are showing event properties and advocating load over DOMContentLoaded. In this case load should not be used.

Comment: @ScottMarcus I myself do not have enough knowledge about `DOMContentLoaded` and hence used `load`. I have updated it and will look into it. Thanks.

Comment: Well, I think you should read the post about load vs. domcontentloaded then and maybe not make recommendations on one vs. the other until you've got it clear.

Comment: Thank you for your response, as @ScottMarcus said I must use the addEventListener() instead to meet the W3C DOM Event Handling Standards. Anyways, your code helped me too understanding other ways in which I can resolve the problem.